# Arduino Make a Servo Reverse When Button is Unpressed

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, servo

Very New to Arduino, i am trying t make it so that when the button is pressed but when the button is unpressed it reverses back. This is the code i am using:

````
Servo myservo;  
int servoPin = 9;
int pushButtonPin =2;
int angle =25;   
int angleStep =5;

void setup() {
 
  Serial.begin(9600);        
  myservo.attach(servoPin);  
  pinMode(pushButtonPin,INPUT_PULLUP);
   
  
}

void loop() {
  while(digitalRead(pushButtonPin) == LOW){
 
  angle = angle + angleStep;

  
    while(digitalRead(pushButtonPin) == HIGH){
      angleStep = -angleStep;
    }
    myservo.write(angle); 
  delay(30); 
 


}```
````

Comment: I forgot to mention that when the button is pressed currently, the motor moves. but does not move back when unpressed

Comment: the loop function already acts as a loop, so you don't any any while at all.  just check if the button is pressed or not with an if and move the motor accordingly

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki thanks - i ammended my code like this - void loop() {
  if(digitalRead(pushButtonPin) == LOW){
 
  angle = angle + angleStep;

  
    if(digitalRead(pushButtonPin) == HIGH){
      angleStep = -angleStep;
    }
    myservo.write(angle); 
  delay(30); 
 


}}

but the same problem occurs, it moves when pressed but does not reverse

Comment: Don't put code as a comment, edit the question. I provided you an answer that checks the button and moves the Servo

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any loop at all since the loop function already acts as a loop.

Just check if the button is pressed o not.

```
Servo myservo;  
int servoPin = 9;
int pushButtonPin =2;
int angle =25;   
int angleStep = 5;

// Modify this to match your Servo Min and max angles (with some margin) 
// I assumed a 180 degree servo
const int MIN_ANGLE = 10;
const int MAX_ANGLE = 170;

void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(9600);        
  myservo.attach(servoPin);  
  pinMode(pushButtonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);     
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(pushButtonPin)) {
    if (angle + angleStep > MAX_ANGLE)
      angle = MAX_ANGLE;
    else  
      angle += angleStep;   
  }
  else {
    if (angle - angleStep < MIN_ANGLE) 
      angle = MIN_ANGLE;
    else
      angle -= angleStep;
  }

  myservo.write(angle); 
  delay(30); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much - this works. Only issue, the motor now moves incredibly slowly, i don't know why

Comment: Edited the question to make the angles always in the range of the servo capabilities